# Overlay image onto live video

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to overlay the inverted image onto the live feed from the webcam. The image is captured using the webcam earlier in the code. I keep getting errors regarding the size of the matrix and number of indices.

```
#set resolution to had
frameWidth = 1920  
frameHeight = 1080
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
# Set initial value of weights
alpha = 0.4
inverted_image = np.asarray(Image.open('inverted.jpg'))
while True:
success, img2 = cap2.read()
cv2.imshow("feed", img2)
foreground = inverted_image
background = img2
# Select the region in the background where we want to add the image and add the images using 
cv2.addWeighted()
added_image = cv2.addWeighted(background[150:250, 150:250, :], alpha, foreground[0:100, 0:100, 
:], 1 - alpha, 0)
# Change the region with the result
background[150:250, 150:250] = added_image
# For displaying current value of alpha(weights)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(background, 'alpha:{}'.format(alpha), (10, 30), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, 
cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow('a', background)
k = cv2.waitKey(10)
# Press q to break
if k == ord('q'):
    break
# press a to increase alpha by 0.1
if k == ord('a'):
    alpha += 0.1
    if alpha >= 1.0:
        alpha = 1.0
# press d to decrease alpha by 0.1
elif k == ord('d'):
    alpha -= 0.1
    if alpha <= 0.0:
        alpha = 0.0




key = cv2.waitKey(10) #effects refresh rate


if key == 27: #kills with Escp

    break
cap2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The size of the image and the webcam feed are both 1920x1080
Thanks

Comment: Please fix the indentation, and try to create a more reproducible code sample. Why there are there both `cap` and `cap2`? What is `cv2.addWeighted()` without arguments? Are you sure the size of the image and webcam feed are 1920x1080 with 3 color channels.  Make sure `inverted_image.shape` and 'img2.shape` are both (1080, 1920, 3). Please post the exact error message, and add the required `import`s to your post.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the cap and cap 2 error. It was there because I use the first cap to create the image earlier in the code. I changed the cap.set(frameWidth) to cap2.set.... and it now works!

Comment: @OliverTaylor please update your indentation and make it a working example. End of Review.